# Google Visualization API Geomap background color

Tags: google-maps, charts, google-visualization

I've got a map generated by Visualization API. Its type is GeoMap.
I'm wondering how I can set a different that original blue background for it. I know that it is very easy to set a color for regions but I need the oceans to be, ie. black. Is it possible to do via API? Maybe I should create some black graphic file that is half permanent and put it at the top of the map? Any other ideas?

Thanks a lot,
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not supported. however you can change the map colors, check Markers Example here:
http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html

Answer (score 3):

The new GeoChart allows this to be done via the 'background' option.  http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html

Answer (score 0):

use this options

```
options = { 

datalessRegionColor: '#29ABE2',

backgroundColor: '#F3F3F3',

colorAxis: {colors: ['#0071BC']},

keepAspectRatio: false,

legend: false,


tooltip: { textStyle: { color: '#0099CB', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: '10'} }

};
```